# Get value from ansible file

Tags: python, bash, split, ansible

I need get values from line with (ansible) file. My lines show:

```
name01.server.com    key1=val1    key2=val2   #comment
name02.server.com    key1=val1    key2="val 2" key3=val3
```

Generally I need only server name val1 and val2, but if I do `split` by space my "val 2" in second row is separated and I get only "val".

The case may be solve with python, bash or another language.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**I need only server name val1 and val2**"*

A: Create a dictionary with the selected data. This should solve the problem, e.g. given the file

```sh
shell> cat my_file
name01.server.com    key1=val1    key2=val2   #comment
name02.server.com    key1=val1    key2="val 2" key3=val3
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|zip(_keys1|zip(_keys2))) }}"
      vars:
        _keys1: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|map('extract', hostvars, 'key1')|list }}"
        _keys2: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|map('extract', hostvars, 'key2')|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i my_file
```

```yaml
  _dict:
    name01.server.com:
    - val1
    - val2
    name02.server.com:
    - val1
    - val 2
```